# Trailing space to superview constraint on a UILabel does not behave

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have following constraints in a UITableViewCell

[image]

This shows correctly in IB when the text is longer than a line, but when it actually renders on the phone, the label just shows a single line that goes out of the screen. Why isn't the "trailing space to superview" constraint working?

Comment: use numberoflineproperty and assign zero.

Comment: It is assigned to 3 at the moment. I don't want it to go beyond 3 lines.